# asyncio: can a task only start when previous task reach a pre-defined stage?

Tags: python-asyncio, process-pool

I am starting with asyncio that I wish to apply to following problem:

- Data is split in chunks.
- A chunk is 1st compressed.
- Then the compressed chunk is written in the file.
- A single file is used for all chunks, so I need to process them one by one.

```py
with open('my_file', 'w+b') as f:
    for chunk in chunks:
        compress_chunk(ch)
        f.write(ch)
```

From this context, to run this process faster, as soon as the `write` step of current iteration starts, could the `compress` step of next iteration be triggered as well?

Can I do that with `asyncio`, keeping a similar `for` loop structure? If yes, could you share some pointers about this?

I am guessing another way to run this in parallel is by using `ProcessPoolExecutor` and splitting fully the `compress` phase from the `write` phase. This means compressing 1st all chunks in different executors.

Only when all chunks are compressed, then starting the writing step .
But I would like to investigate the 1st approach with `asyncio` 1st, if it makes sense.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Bests

Comment: Maybe the start of an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69331788/synchronize-asyncio-queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a producer-consumer model. As long as there is one producer and one consumer, you will have the correct order. For your use-case, that's all you'll benefit from. Also, you should use the `aioFiles` library. Standard file IO will mostly block your main compression/producer thread and you won't see much speedup. Try something like this:

```py
async def produce(queue, chunks):
    for chunk in chunks:
        compress_chunk(ch)
        await queue.put(i)


async def consume(queue):
    with async with aiofiles.open('my_file', 'w') as f:
        while True:
            compressed_chunk = await Q.get()
            await f.write(b'Hello, World!')
            queue.task_done()


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    producer = asyncio.create_task(producer(queue, chunks))
    consumer = asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))

    # wait for the producer to finish
    await producer

    # wait for the consumer to finish processing and cancel it
    await queue.join()
    consumer.cancel()
 
asyncio.run(main())
```

https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles

[Using asyncio.Queue for producer-consumer flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582685/using-asyncio-queue-for-producer-consumer-flow)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Andrew-Harelson. It seems like I could also use fsspec instead of aioFiles    (https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/async.html)    I will investigate this! Thanks again!